# block next component call until promise complete of another component in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-promise, angular2-services

I have googled a lot for this, but unfortunately i did'nt get anything.

**The Context**

I have a component where i have two child selector like below.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-panel">
    <navbar-cmp></navbar-cmp>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <!--<div *ngIf="!isMap()">
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>-->
  </div>
    <div class="sidebar" data-active-color="blue" data-background-color="white">
        <!-- <div class="sidebar" data-color="red" data-image=""> -->
        <sidebar-cmp></sidebar-cmp>
        <!--<div class="sidebar-background" style="background-image: url(assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg)"></div>-->
    </div>

</div>
```

So according to this nav-bar component will be called and nav-bar contain a promise which take some time. But my flow go to side-bar component before complete the promise in nav-bar component.
But i want that control should not go to side-bar component until it clear the promise in nav-bar component.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'navbar-cmp',
    templateUrl: './navbar-cmp.html',
    })
    export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {
    promiseIsCompleted :boolean = false;
    constructor(private signUpService: SignUpService) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        youPromise.then(()=>{
           this.promiseIsCompleted = true;
       })
    }
```

html :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-panel">
    <navbar-cmp #navbar ></navbar-cmp>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <!--<div *ngIf="!isMap()">
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>-->
  </div>
    <div class="sidebar" data-active-color="blue" data-background-color="white">
        <!-- <div class="sidebar" data-color="red" data-image=""> -->
        <sidebar-cmp *ngIf="navbar.promiseIsCompleted"></sidebar-cmp>
        <!--<div class="sidebar-background" style="background-image: url(assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg)"></div>-->
    </div>

</div>
```